# How to edit paypal hosted button using paypal api

Tags: paypal

Is there any way to edit the hosted paypal button from my own website using paypal api? If yes then where i can find the api embedding link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with PayPal's button manager API. You can find all of the details here:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/paypal-payments-standard-and-button-manager